# why path dn in database must be filled?

Tags: symfony, ldap

I have a question with symfony2 and ldap authentication.

In order to connect a user I need to fill the field "dn" in database with the complete path.

Even if I have made the configuration in app/config/config.yml with the baseDN, it appears that this info is not take in account.

So why did I need to fill this field because for the security it's sucks.

So if you have any solution or hint I'll take it.

Thanks